# How can Doru Doru work against seastone

Tags: one-piece

We have twice seen Mr.3 open seastone cage/cuffs with his wax powers, once in Alabasta and once in the war of the summit. How can his wax key not melt once inside the keyhole?

Comment: My guess is that it is something tied to the fact that seastone would prevent him from manifesting wax, but once it is already manifest it is probably separate from his power and thus not affected by the seastone.

Comment: @Cyberson - I don't think that's the case because we know that, for example, if a person is turned into a doll by Sugar, then once she touches seastone he will get back to normal. That never happened, but that is the hypothesis anyway.

Comment: @TGamer no, cyberson is right, power like Mr. 3 are not affected by seastone after manifestation. seastone has effect on devil fruit user only which makes them powerless and weak

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [seastome wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Seastone)

> Seastone only works upon direct and constant contact.

Which means it works only on devil fruit user not on the power or material they produce using power.

> It has been shown that although a Devil Fruit user loses his/her powers when in contact with the Seastone, said powers can still be used on and affect the Seastone. Example is when Mr. 3's candle wax key could open Seastone cuffs and cell doors, though this may be because the locks themselves are not made of Seastone or **because the wax has no Devil Fruit powers inside it**, as shown when he unlocked Ace's Seastone handcuffs. Another example is when Shiki levitated battleships in Marineford, despite the hulls being lined with Seastone. Trafalgar Law was also able to switch Seastone chains with regular ones, using his abilities.

Another example is Aokiji Kuzan's ice formation power, which he uses it to make ice road on the sea to travel in his bicycle. Here the ice doesn't melt just because it came in contact with the sea.

And this is just the guess but seastone might melt if comes in contact with Akainu's lava where the temperature of lava is greater than melting point of seastone.

Comment: Why then, was Doflamingo unable to slash the factory with his birdcage?

Comment: **coz seastone is hard as diamond**, and if zoro was not able to cut seastone then that doflamingo's bird cage is nothing special :D

Comment: Okay, but Franky exclaimed how it is the cage is powerless against the factory simply because it is made by an ability

Comment: cutting and using devil fruit on seastone are different thing, AFAIK law was only the one who cut the seastone(did he really or not discussion is still going on) for complete answer on birdcage and seastone, you will need to ask another question

Comment: If the seastone in the factory really affected  Doffys string/cage wouldn't the string that came in contact with the factory disappear?

Comment: @Gravinco no, as explained in my answer, it works only on devil fruit user not on the power or material they produce using power

Comment: @mirroroftruth That's what I'm saying... IF the factory (read seastone) would have had an effect on the strings, the strings should disappear but they didn't so... no effect on the material

Comment: @Gravinco yes that's right. no effect on material only on devil fruit user

Answer (score 0):

oda stated that devil fruit can't be affected after activating it, we can see it clearly when MR3 in marineford made a key to rescue ace, after the key was formed they could open, and also happened with aokiji when he did the ace age, so that means the seastones won't affecte on the devil fruit abbility after it activated